# Sum and multiply matrices of different size

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have two matrices in Matlab: `A` of size `GxM` and `B` of size `DxM`. I want to create a matrix `C` of size `GxD` such that `C(g,d)=sum(A(g,:).*B(d,:))/M`.

Let me explain better with an example

```
clear
A=[1  2  3;
   4  5  6;
   7  8  9;
   10 11 12]; %GxM

B=[14 15 16;
   17 18 19]; %DxM

G=size(A,1);
D=size(B,1);
M=size(A,2);
```

The matrix `C` can be obtained as follows:

```
C=zeros(G,D);
for g=1:G
    for d=1:D
        C(g,d)=sum(A(g,:).*B(d,:))/M;
    end
end
```

I want to avoid this double loop because my code involves matrices of much bigger dimensions. Could you suggest something vectorised?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an extreme form of vectorization, because what you have is basically a matrix product. In order to see this, consider

```
C(i,j) = sum_k A(i,k)*B(j,k)/M = 1/M * sum_k A(i,k)*B(j,k),
```

so defining the transpose of `B` as `Bt` we have

```
C(i,j) = 1/M * sum_k A(i,k) * Bt(k,j)
```

where the sum is by definition the `(i,j)` element of the matrix product `A * Bt`. In other words, what you need is

```
C = (A * B.')/M;
```

Using your example inputs and computing `C2` according to the above:

```
>> C

C =

   30.6667   36.6667
   75.6667   90.6667
  120.6667  144.6667
  165.6667  198.6667

>> C2

C2 =

   30.6667   36.6667
   75.6667   90.6667
  120.6667  144.6667
  165.6667  198.6667
```